# Changing the x labels in a Liferay 7.2 barchart

Tags: liferay, bar-chart

I'm trying to display a bar chart following this example in Liferay 7.2; https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028832612-Bar-Charts. It works fine but is there a way to change the labels of the "X" axis from "0, 1, 2" to something else?

Comment: Did you look at the `BarChartConfig` class that's referenced in that article? Odds are that it has more methods and one of them might do the trick.

Comment: Oh yes I did.
One of the method is barChartConfig.getAxisX().setLabel(). It sounds good but it does not do the trick.....

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
_barChartConfig.getAxisX().setType(AxisX.Type.CATEGORY);
_barChartConfig.getAxisX().addCategories(myCategories);
```

Where `myCategories` is a List object with the labels you'd like to display under each bar.